# Solution of Second Order Nonlinear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $y''( 1+y'^2)=0$

I couldn't do any comment for this question. Can anyone help me? Sincerely thanks.

Comment: If a product is equal to $0$, you can split this product into two equations with a "or" between them...

Comment: Further hint: if $y$ is real, $1+y'^2 \ne 0$.

Comment: yes just found the result is lncosx + c :)

Comment: @kidonat: $\ln\cos x+c$, are you serious ?

Comment: actually Wolfram alpha found it '))

Answer (score 0):

Solving $y''( 1+y'^2)=0$ As it's factor of two number, neither $y''=0$ or $1+y'^2=0$

$y''=0  \iff y=c_1x+c_2$ this is the first solution. Then the second case:
$1+y'^2=0   \iff y=c_1-ix$ or $y=c_1+ix$

These are solution of this equation

Answer (score 0):

$$y''=0\to y=ax+b.$$

$$y'^2+1=0\to\text{ impossible}.$$